# If Else inside jQuery each not working

Tags: jquery, if-statement, each

If is not blocking the execution of else statement. Help plase!

```
function checarZero() {
  $(".ps-form-entry--progressbar").each(function() {
    var valorPerc = $(this).val();
    if (parseFloat(valorPerc) === 0) {
      psLib.NotifyShowHide(
        'alert:Você não distribuiu a renda vitalícia.');
      event.preventDefault();
    } else {
      $("#btn-continuar").fadeIn("fast");
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `event` is undefined. 
Given the snippet you provided is your code, you should see an error in your JS console.

The `event` variable should be passed into `checarZero` function, for it to be cancelled.
From the snippet, it's hard to say what event you're looking for, if you just want to stop the execution of `.each` loop you must `return false;`

Answer (score 0):

Just `return false` to break the loop.